# Is google drive API limits per account or project?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-drive-api

I have a project relay on google drive API and i hit API limits all the time.
And i need to know if google drive API limits is set per accounts or per projects?
And if it is per project, is there any limitation per account?
Thsnks

Answer (score 2):

Google Drive API limits are subject to limits based on per project, per user and per time frame.

You can see your quota by creating a project in the [Google Developer's Console](https://console.developers.google.com/apis/), and from the Burger Menu (☰) menu in the top left following:

```
☰ > IAM & admin > Quotas
```

From here you can see your quotas for each service, clicking on `Google Drive API` will bring you to the Drive API specific page which shows you how many Queries per day, Queries per 100 seconds, and Queries per 100 seconds per user that the selected project is subject to.

The Developers console also has graphs showing your traffic and request history to all API services, so is a good place to see where you are hitting your limits and potentially reduce this where you can.

There is a [batch update method of Drive](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/batch) which if you are making multiple requests can significantly reduce your number of requests, but as mentioned on the [Google Developers blog](https://developers.googleblog.com/2018/03/discontinuing-support-for-json-rpc-and.html) they are deprecating this endpoint on 12<sup>th</sup> August 2020 and so API specific batch endpoints would need to be used.

Comment: Thanks. I don't know why Google doesn't add this information with the default quotas somewhere in their documentation.